# Dynamic cells with different actions

Tags: uitableview, tableview

Right now I have a dynamic Table where all cells lead to the same detailview. Is it possible to make one of the cells do something else than the others? Like opening another view, show alert i.e. If so, how? :)

Best Regards Chris

Comment: You can do whatever you decide is necessary in your table view delegate's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.  You get an indexPath in that method and can use it to look at the data the cell represents to see what should happen in response.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up. So basically, I can set one IndexPath to handle the cells which lead to the DetailView and make another IndexPath which handles the rest of the cells which open an alert, in the same Table? :)

Comment: Sort of.  It's more a case of looking at the indexPath you're given, rather than setting or making anything.  Usually indexPath.rox points to some data you use to configure the cell.  Somewhere in that piece of data should be an indication of how you want its selection to work.